# ZF3 PhpRenderer not finding template path

Tags: php, templates, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I know there are dozen of questions about PHPRenderer not finding the path of a template, but I think the problem is quite different here.

First, the goal is to render a view to a variable in order to send it to a PDF Renderer (I use ZF3 TCPDF module). If there is any better way to do that, please tell me.

Here is roughly the architecture of the project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pfEx.jpg

In `AlertAction()` of `ToolsController`, I return the view like this, and it works, which make me think the template path is alright.

```
$view = new ViewModel();
$view->setTemplate('tools/tools/alert');
return $view;
```

However, when I try to render the same view with the same path in `exportPDFAction()`, it does not work and gives the following error.

> Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "tools/tools/alert"; resolver could not resolve to a file

The code in `exportPDFAction()` is:

```
$view = new ViewModel();
$renderer = new PhpRenderer();
$view->setTemplate('tools/tools/alert');
$html = $renderer->render($view);
```

I assume the last line screws it as it is the difference, but I can't get why, does anyone have any clue ?

Quite all the topics about Template path on SO were talking about the template map in `module.config.php`, but I think this is not the problem here since it works perfectly in `AlertAction()`.

**EDIT**

The PhpRenderer is injected in the controller directly in module.config.php:

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        ToolsController::class => function($container) {
            return new ToolsController(
                $container->get(Adapter::class),
                $container->get(\TCPDF::class),
                $container->get(PhpRenderer::class)
            );
        },
    ],
],
```

**EDIT 2**

This is the controller constructor:

```
public function __construct($db, $tcpdf, $renderer)
{
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->tcpdf = $tcpdf;
    $this->renderer = $renderer;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting might be due to the fact your Renderer is not injected via the Factory.

Try:

```
class MyCustomControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        /** @var \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer $renderer */
        $renderer = $container->get('ViewRenderer')

        return new MyCustomController($renderer);
    }
}
```

In the Controller, require it be set in the `__construct()` function:

```
public function __construct(PhpRenderer $renderer)
{
    // ... set it somewhere, e.g.:
    $this->setRenderer($renderer);
}
```

Then use it in your function:

```
$view = new ViewModel();
$renderer = $this->getRenderer();
$view->setTemplate('tools/tools/alert');
$html = $renderer->render($view);
```

---

#### Why, you ask?

Because the Renderer is configured via the Zend Configuration. You can find that in the `\Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManageFactory` class. The **alias** configuration provided is the following:

```
'ViewPhpRenderer'                      => 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer',
'ViewRenderer'                         => 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer',
'Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface' => 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer',
```

The **alias**'es are mapped to **Factory**:

```
'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer' => ViewPhpRendererFactory::class,
```

That Factory is:

```
class ViewPhpRendererFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  ContainerInterface $container
     * @param  string $name
     * @param  null|array $options
     * @return PhpRenderer
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $name, array $options = null)
    {
        $renderer = new PhpRenderer();
        $renderer->setHelperPluginManager($container->get('ViewHelperManager'));
        $renderer->setResolver($container->get('ViewResolver'));

        return $renderer;
    }
}
```

As such, it has some presets included when you use it with `$this->getRenderer`, namely it has the `HelperPluginManager` and the `Resolver` set. So it knows where to get additional resources (if needed) and it knows how to resolve (ie render) a View.

Comment: Actually it is, I forgot to include this part to the post (see the edit). But I need to add the configuration of phprenderer you mentionned in the second part  ?

Comment: No, that package should be included as part of the `zendframework/zend-view` package (check in the `composer.lock` file of the project). To make sure, you do **not** do `new PhpRenderer()` in the Controller class, right? Because you should be using an injected one (due to requirements I mentioned in the answer).

Comment: I just set it as controller property in the constructor (see edit 2), and it is not used anywhere else

Comment: Oh actually i did a `new PhpRenderer()`, you're right, I replaced it with $this->renderer and now I only have a TCPDF error, thanks a lot